# System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (415) UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am having problems with a bit of code that accesses a restful web service.
Running this code, it errors out at var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); and the exception returned is: "System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (415) UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE."

```
    public bool CreateAccount(string myUsername, string url, string authtoken) {
        try {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.MediaType="application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Accept="application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
            headers.Add("Authorization: Token"+authtoken);
            httpWebRequest.Headers = headers;

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {
                streamWriter.Write("{username : '"+myUsername+"'}");
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); // Fails on this line.
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return true;

        } catch (WebException e) {
            throw e;
            return false;
        }
        //return true;
    }
```

I have tried various things for the ContentType, MediaType, and Accept, but the working example given to me by the developer of the service supplies -H "Content-Type: application/json" to curl, so it would seem that "application/json" is the correct value. He also does --data-binary, which I assume streamWriter does for me.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

When I do:

```
        WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
        headers.Add("Authorization: Token "+authtoken);
        httpWebRequest.Headers = headers;
```

I accidentally blow away all of the existing headers that were created by doing:

```
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.MediaType="application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept="application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
```

The answer is to move the code where I create the header with the auth token above the code where I set the other headers.

Answer (score 0):

One known reason for this error is mismatch of service name in service file and config file. That is Your service name and configuration service name don't match"

Right click on .svc file in Solution Explorer and select "View Markup" and paste correct sevice name it into the .config.

Comment: Also prior to the above step, it is important to see if can you browse the service directly.

Comment: I have no service file. I didn't think you needed one if you were hitting a RESTful service.

Comment: What tool you use to look at serivce? I suggest to use HTTP4E client or RESTClient.

Comment: Again it is important  to see if you can access the service outside of C#.

Comment: Like I already said, the developer provided me with a working curl call that can successfully access the service. It's not the service, it's my code.

Comment: What if you use the following code:
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();

Comment: OK I replaced var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); with WebResponse httpResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); and it now errors out on the replaced line, and it gives the same error.